# SyntaxError: "+=" is an unexpected token

Tags: python

First time working with Python and can't get the add and assign operator working.  The interpreter keeps saying `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
def addRead(self, i=1):
    if(i<1):
        return self.getNumPages += i
```

Also tried to no avail.

```
def addRead(self, i=1):
    if(i<1):
        return 
    self.getNumPages += i
```

Comment: in Python, assignments are not expressions.

Comment: If you don't know what an expression is, then you need to google way more than you did so far.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Floris This link says "+=" was the add and assign operator for python.  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm  If "+=" is not the add and assign operator, what is?

Comment: So you want to change a value or return a value. If you want to do both you need two lines of code.

Comment: @Floris -- I changed the code to two lines of code, however, it just gives me a typeerror.  "Unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'method' and 'int'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you get the message that `getNumPages` is a method, the most intuitive way would be to call it to get its result.

But this contradicts to what you are doing:

If it is a data attribute, `+=` would work. But you can't re-assign something to the result of a method call.

So, depending what you try to do, one of the following things are the way to go:

```
numpages = self.getNumPages() # first step: get the result
numpages += i # get the new value
# or just: numpages = self.getNumPages() + i
self.setNumPages(numpages) # set the new value would be the equivalent of the += stuff.
return numpages
```

If you don't want to reassign the value, you'd  just do

```
return self.getNumPages() + i
```

Be aware, however, that getter and setter methods in Python are very unusual. You either use the attributes directly, or you wrap them in a property which is essentialy a kind of "built-in getter/setter" stuff.

```
class Whatever:
    def getNumPages(self):
        return self._numpages
    def setNumPages(self, newone)
        self._numpages = newone
    # now the property stuff:
    @property
    def numpages(self): # the getter
        return self.getNumPages()
    @numpages.setter
    def numpages(self, newone)
        self.setNumPages(newone)
```

This property (which is essentially useless and would only be used if setting or getting is supposed to have side-effects or to modify/calculate something else as well) enables us to do

```
self.numpages += i
return self.numpages
```

which could be what you want.

Answer (score 3):

`a += b` is a statement, so does not evaluate to a value. Thus it does not make sense to return it. Split it over lines, returning the wanted portion:

```
self.getNumPages += i
return self.getNumPages
```

Comment: Again, I originally had that as my code, but get a "Unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'method' and 'int'" error.

Comment: Well, `getNumPages` is obviously a method and `i` is obviously an attribute. How exactly are you wanting to add them? Do you get the difference between `+=` and `+`?

Comment: Of course I get the difference between the "add and assign" and add operator.  I don't see what that has to do with my error.

Comment: It's hardly "of course" if you've demonstrated that you're extremely new to the language ;). The rest of my question still applies. How are you wanting to get them? Have you defined `getNumPages` yourself? *Why* do you have `getNumPages` and not just a `pages` attribute?